# Помогите с задачей

Tags: python

Есть такая задача:

Максим очень любит бутерброды. Для приготовления полноценного бутерброда ему требуется 4 ингредиента: 1 кусок хлеба, 3 куска сыра, 2 куска колбасы и 1 яйцо.

Среди запасов Максим нашёл A кусков хлеба, B кусков сыра, C кусков колбасы и D яиц. Определите, сколько полноценных бутербродов сможет сделать Максим.

Входные данные
Ввод содержит целые числа A, B, C, D, (1 ≤ A, B, C, D ≤ 1000) — соответственно количество имеющихся кусков хлеба, кусков сыра, кусков колбасы и яиц.

Выходные данные
Выведите одно целое число — количество полноценных бутербродов, которые может сделать Максим.

```
входные данные

2 6 4 2

выходные данные

2
```

Полное решение не прошу, хотя бы натолкнуть на него

Comment: Свои какие есть попытки добавьте ;)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Можно было конечно не так многословно это сделать, но так понятнее

```py
# Необходимое количество ингредиентов каждого вида
BREAD_PER_PORTION = 1
CHEESE_PER_PORTION = 3
MEAT_PER_PORTION = 2
EGGS_PER_PORTION = 1

# Принимаем пользовательский ввод
bread, cheese, meat, eggs = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

# Считаем на сколько порций хватает каждого ингредиента
# для этого подойдт целочисленное деление
bread_portions = bread // BREAD_PER_PORTION
cheese_portions = cheese // CHEESE_PER_PORTION
meat_portions = meat // MEAT_PER_PORTION
eggs_portions = eggs // EGGS_PER_PORTION

# Находим лимитирующий ингридиент, то есть 
# тот, которого хватает на наименьшее кол-во порций
result = min([
    bread_portions,
    cheese_portions,
    meat_portions,
    eggs_portions
])

print(result)
```